# amchart getting json data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, amcharts

I try to make a chart with amcharts. But at the moment I have no success. This is how I generate my json file:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
echo $prefix . " {\n";
echo '  "category": "' . $row['tstamp'] . '",' . "\n";

echo '  "value": ' . $row['temp'] . '' . "\n";
echo " }";
$prefix = ",\n";
}
echo "\n]";
```

The html source code can be viewed here:
http://bitfreun.de/werte.php

In the Chrome console i get an error:
[image: Chrome error message in developer console]

Comment: do **NOT** build your own json. build a php array, then [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode) it.

Comment: why should i not do that?

Comment: for the exact reason you're here... if you're building your own json strings, then YOU are responsible for guaranteeing you're producing **VALID** json. if you json_encode(), then all that work is done for you automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you get numbers like "30.500" in your output I can only assume that your values are stored in VARCHAR type column in MySQL. And so it happens they contain extra symbols at the end, probably resulting from the failure to properly sanitize your data inputs.

Apart from obvious solution that you should switch to using FLOAT type columns, there is something you can do now to fix this. Just cast your return number into float:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
  echo $prefix . " {\n";
  echo '  "category": "' . $row['tstamp'] . '",' . "\n";
  echo '  "value": ' . ( (float) $row['temp'] ) . "\n";
  echo " }";
  $prefix = ",\n";
}
echo "\n]";
```

It is also a good idea to let PHP build your JSON:

```
$data = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
  $data[] = array(
    'category' => $row['tstamp'],
    'value' => (float) $row['temp']
  );
}
echo json_encode( $data );
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Does anyone know how to code the javascript part, that hour-values are on the chart:
http://bitfreun.de/werte.php